# How can I open windows explorer to a certain directory specified by user?

Tags: c#, directory, explorer

My code,

```
string pcname = @"remotepc";
string path = @"dir\sub\";
string remotepath = @"\\" + pcname + @"\C$\" + path;

System.Diagnostics.Process pexplorer = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pexplorer.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
pexplorer.StartInfo.Arguments = remotepath;
pexplorer.Start();
```

`remotepath` contains string like "\\remotepc\C$\dir\sub". If I copy this string into `addressbar` of Windows Explorer, it shows me this directory.

But into my program Explorer is opened at home directory.
When I look at `pexplorer.StartInfoArguments`, it contains something like 
"\\\\remotepc\\C$\\Users\\use\\AppData\\Local\\"

If I set `remotepath` in program,

```
System.Diagnostics.Process pexplorer = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
pexplorer.StartInfo.FileName = "explorer.exe";
pexplorer.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\remotepc\C$\dir\sub";
pexplorer.Start();
```

It works correctly, what is wrong here?

Comment: a tip. don't concatenate path yourselves. Instead, use `System.IO.Path.Combine()`. e.g. `var uncPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(@"\\" , pcname, "c$", path);`

Comment: the only difference i see in the two code blocks is, that the first path contains a trailing backslash. the second code block doesn't.

Comment: I can reproduce your symptoms if I mispell some parts of the path. In this case the explorer opens up the local document folder. So check if your paths are correct.

Comment: I agree with @Steve. Trailing backslash doesn't make any difference. In either case it will work.

Comment: @AcidJunkie, System.IO.Path.Combine() can't accept more than 3 args. Should I combine Combine?

Comment: It depends on the .net framework version. Older versions only had the following signature: `string Combine(string,string)`. That means you have to repeatedly call to get the same result or create your own helper class which provides this missing funcionality

Comment: Strange problem with net access to some directories. Path is correct, all work properly.
Thanks 4 all.

Comment: Can't you just call `pexploere.Start(@"c:\somefolder\somesubfolder");`?  No need to start explorer.exe directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"explorer.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"file:\\\" + @"Q:\somepath\...";
p.Start();
```

The problem is purely the URL. Adding "file:\\" to your full path did solve my problem.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freeassociations/archive/2005/05/19/420059.aspx
csharphardcoreprogramming.wordpress.com